# I'm stuck: 'CS50, PSET 1, Credit', only prints 'INVALID' despite various conditionals

Tags: c, function, cs50

I wrote this program which is meant to check the validity of a card number inputted by the user; outputting the type of card, if valid, or 'INVALID'.

Even though most of the functions work individually, together, when running the program, I only get one output.

Where am I going wrong?

My code is:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

long get_number(void);
int calculate_checksum(long number);
int calculate_length(long number);
int calculate_startd(long number);
int calculate_startdv(int startd);

int main(void)
{
    long number = get_number();
    int checksum = calculate_checksum(number);
    int length = calculate_length(number);
    int startd = calculate_startd(number);
    int startdv = calculate_startdv(startd);

    if (checksum == 0 && (length == 13 || length == 16) && startdv == 4)
    {
        printf("VISA\n");
    }
    else if (checksum == 0 && length == 15 && (startd == 34 || startd == 37))
    {
        printf("AMEX\n");
    }
    else if (checksum ==0 && length == 16 && (startd >= 51 && startd <= 55))
    {
        printf("MASTERCARD\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("INVALID\n");
    }
}

// get number from user
long get_number(void)
{
    long number;
    do
    {
        number = get_long("Number: ");
    } while (number <= 0);

    return number;
}

// calculate checksum
int calculate_checksum(long number)
{
    int d1;
    int d2;
    int d22;
    int p1 = 0;
    int p2 = 0;
    int total;
    int checksum;

    do
    {
        d1 = number % 10;
        number /= 10;
        p1 += d1;
        d2 = number % 10;
        number/= 10;
        d22 = d2 * 2;
        p2 += d22;
    } while (number > 0);

    total = p1 + p2;
    checksum = total % 10;

    return checksum;
}

// calculating the length of the card number
int calculate_length(long number)
{
    int length = 0;

    do
    {
        number /= 10;
        ++length;
    } while (number > 0);

    return length;
}

// work out/ isolate the starting digits of the number
int calculate_startd(long number)
{
    int startd;

    do
    {
        startd = number % 10;
        number /= 10;
    } while (number > 100);

    return startd;
}

// isolating the first digit for visa cards
int calculate_startdv(int startd)
{
    int startdv;

    do
    {
        startdv = startd % 10;
        startd /= 10;
    } while (startd > 10);

    return startdv;
}
```

Comment: What did you enter where you got "invalid" but expected something else?

Comment: You should definitely read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: @mkrieger1 Thank you for the link you shared! I was using valid card number examples from paypal; my program worked with them (the checksum and length calculator) until I tried to actually define the card type ahh x

Comment: Hint: when dividing a big integer by 10, the quotient will have 2 digits when it is less than 100. It will have 1 digit when it is less than 10... Re-write the "start" functions with fewer variables....

Comment: @Fe2O3 I am not sure I understand how to rewrite it with fewer variables, I thought they already only take one variable input each? I'm sorry, I'm a beginner!

Comment: `int func( int n ) { while( n >= 100 ) n = n / 10; return n; }` ... Function parameters are variables you can use, too...

Comment: PS: VISA prefix: 40 <= n <= 49 ??? No need for a second function to strip down to a single digit... (Everyone was a beginner at one time. Don't apologise... It's perfectly natural.. `:-)`

Comment: Do you notice how you're doing a lot of breaking down numbers into digits?  Sometimes multiple times for the same number? Credit card "numbers" are digit sequences, but not *bona fide* numbers in a mathematical sense.  Consider, for example, that leading zeroes in a CCN are significant.  Using a representation that gives you direct access to the digits would be to your advantage.  Such as a string.

Answer (score 0):

In Luhn's Algorithms we multiply every second number by 2 and then if any multiplication doesn't yield a single digit number we add up all the digits of that number and then move ahead.

Look at the fourth substep of the very first step in the image. It says:

> Now let’s add those products’ digits (i.e., not the products themselves) together

[image: Luhn's Algorithm]

The problem is in this particular block of code:

```
    do
    {
        d1 = number % 10;
        number /= 10;
        p1 += d1;
        d2 = number % 10;
        number/= 10;
        d22 = d2 * 2;
        p2 += d22;
    } while (number > 0);
```

You can correct it somewhat like this:

```
do
{
    p2 += d22 % 10;
    d22 /= 10;
}
while (d2 > 0);
```

It will automatically take care of whether the the product is one digit or not.